# Bootstrap 3 tables don't work properly with Meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

Bootstrap tables don't display like they are supposed to when I use them with Meteor.  `table-striped` doesn't work and the padding is off.

I've tried using the bootstrap-3 package as well as a base meteor app with the css linked to a CDN.

Does anyone know what is going on?

[image]

Here is the meteor html

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Default</p>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <p>Table-striped</p>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    <p>Table-bordered</p>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It appears that the problem has something to do with the missing `<tbody>` element which is usually automatically added by the browser. Interesting - I ran into this same problem today.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to wrap the table content with `<tbody>`:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```